# trying to copy a char pointer using memcpy, getting an error

Tags: c, char, memcpy

so I want to copy a char pointer, asked a friend and he said to use memcpy... so I am trying to do this:

```
charFilenameAndPath=strtok(filename,".");
memcpy=(charFilename,charFilenameAndPath, sizeof(charFilenameAndPath));
```

and the compiler is spitting out this:

```
uTrackSpheres.cpp:176: error: assignment of function ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’
uTrackSpheres.cpp:176: error: cannot convert ‘unsigned int’ to ‘void*(void*, const void*, size_t)throw ()’ in assignment
```

I also tried using strlen instead of sizeof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second line:

```
memcpy=(charFilename,charFilenameAndPath, sizeof(charFilenameAndPath));
```

there is a spurious `=` sign.

Once you fix that, your call is not correct anyway.  `charFilenameAndPath` is the return value from `strtok()`, so it must be a `char *`.  So, you are copying `sizeof(char *)` bytes to `charFilename`, you probably want `strlen(charFilenameAndPath)+1` bytes instead (or you can use `strcpy()`).  In any case, you should make sure that `strtok()` didn't return `NULL` and that `charFilename` has enough space.

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy` is followed by a `=` and should not be.  The error message says you are trying to assign a new value to the symbol `memcpy`, which isn't what you want to do.